# How to link two different tables in one relational table in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have two different tables client and admin, i want to add relation in one table post has many relation. Overall scenario is client and admin can multiple posts. How can do it in laravel?

Comment: Take a look at [one-to-many polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations). The example from the docs can be applied nearly 1:1 to your problem.

Comment: This one: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations